# can't access web application over a LAN using virtual host name,but it is accessible via IP address of wamp server machine

Tags: php

This is my host file,where i have make some changes

```
#127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.51.75       cryptologic.com
```

Although ,my site can be accessible through above stated IP address but, not using domain_name

Comment: Since you've provided no useful details, e.g. Apache configuration, we can't help you.

Comment: Did you define any alias in Apache config?

Comment: ok! What i am trying to say is that, i have created virtual host name for my site by making changes to windows HOST file and, this is where i put my site name in httpd.config file in WAMP server.

Answer (score 2):

Have you configured a virtual host in your wamp server ?

If not follow this link:
http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/creating-multiple-virtual-websites-in-wampserver/

Answer (score 1):

assuming this is Apache, in your apache directory you will find a conf/extra folder, in it is a file called httpd-vhosts.conf. You'll need to create a virtual host there

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.51.75>
  DocumentRoot "//whereever/path/your/root/is"
  Servername cryptologic.com
</VirtualHost>
```

After that, restart Apache and you should be ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need something like this in your httpd-vhosts.conf of your apache settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\thefolderyouneed"
 ServerName "cryptologic.com"
 ServerAlias "*.cryptologic.com"
 <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\thefolderyouneed">
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```